# How can I split a large tab delimited text file into separate files by date field and use the date in the file name

Tags: powershell, csv, text

I have a very large text file 400K+ lines. I need to separate it into multiple files. I currently have it separate by the 3rd ([2]) column and set the text file to that name, but those files are still too large. I would like to separate by name and month if possible.

File looks like this:

```
7/1/2022 9:00   7/1/2022 10:00  25823-0001
7/1/2022 10:00  7/1/2022 11:00  25823-0001 ...
7/1/2022 11:00  7/1/2022 12:00  25823-0001 ...
7/1/2022 12:00  7/1/2022 13:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 13:00  7/2/2022 14:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 14:00  7/2/2022 15:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 15:00  7/2/2022 16:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 16:00  7/2/2022 17:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 17:00  7/2/2022 18:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 18:00  8/1/2022 19:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 19:00  8/1/2022 20:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 20:00  8/1/2022 21:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 21:00  8/1/2022 22:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 22:00  8/1/2022 23:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 23:00  8/2/2022 0:00   25823-0001 ...
8/2/2022 0:00   8/2/2022 1:00   25823-0001 ...
8/2/2022 1:00   8/2/2022 2:00   25823-0001 ...
```

So the file would end up being 25823-0001_202207.txt and contain

```
7/1/2022 9:00   7/1/2022 10:00  25823-0001
7/1/2022 10:00  7/1/2022 11:00  25823-0001 ...
7/1/2022 11:00  7/1/2022 12:00  25823-0001 ...
7/1/2022 12:00  7/1/2022 13:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 13:00  7/2/2022 14:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 14:00  7/2/2022 15:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 15:00  7/2/2022 16:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 16:00  7/2/2022 17:00  25823-0001 ...
7/2/2022 17:00  7/2/2022 18:00  25823-0001 ...
```

25823-0001_202208.txt would contain

```
8/1/2022 18:00  8/1/2022 19:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 19:00  8/1/2022 20:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 20:00  8/1/2022 21:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 21:00  8/1/2022 22:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 22:00  8/1/2022 23:00  25823-0001 ...
8/1/2022 23:00  8/2/2022 0:00   25823-0001 ...
8/2/2022 0:00   8/2/2022 1:00   25823-0001 ...
8/2/2022 1:00   8/2/2022 2:00   25823-0001 ...
```

I currently use this code to split the files:

```
foreach($file in $source){
  $fileIn = New-Object IO.StreamReader $file
  #$header = $fileIn.ReadLine()
while ($line = $fileIn.ReadLine())
  {
    $newFile = "$(($line -split "\t")[2]).txt"
    if ($newFile -ne $currentFile)
      {...
```

I tried editing the code to this:

```
$newFile = "$(($line -split "\t")[2,0]).txt"
```

but obviously, that wont work due to the format of the date field.

> Update
> The below solution seems to work, but I still get this error message:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

I tried adding .trim() to the $fields[0] line thinking maybe there was whitespace, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the line into a variable first, then use the [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) class to parse and reformat the date:

```sh
$fields    = $line -split '\t'
$namePart1 = $fields[2]
$date      = [DateTime]::ParseExact($fields[0], 'M\/d\/yyyy H\:m', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$namePart2 = $date.ToString('yyyyMM')
$newFile   = "${namePart1}_$namePart2"
```

- In the `ParseExact()` call, the 2nd argument specifies a [custom date and time format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Certain characters like `/` and `:` are [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals) which must be `\`-escaped to use them as literal characters.
- In `"${namePart1}_$namePart2"`, the curly braces are used to make sure the underscore is not interpreted as part of the variable name.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, however, I get errors on every line. It does seem to still work, but I need to figure out the error issue. 

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @razielxx My bad, I used `h` instead of `H` for the hour format, which restricted it to the 12 hour range. For 24 hour range, big letter has to be used.

Comment: you are a rockstar! That was it!! Thank you so much.